# is there a way to disable Windows from switching window focus when I am typing?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, typing, window-focus, user-experience

Sometimes when I am typing in a notepad, command prompt, webpage, or the file explorer address bar, or even any other place where typing is allowed, it happens that the currently active window loses focus and a confirmation dialog pops open.

For example, when I have started a long-running copy/move operation in File Explorer, and whilst waiting for it to complete I start working on some other task that requires typing. Immersed in typing sentences or commands, suddenly a popup-window jumps on screen! But I have already instructed my fingers to type in some sentences/commands, and I have no way to make my fingers stop at this high speed! The popup-confirmation dialog then receives some "random" keystrikes from my typing, and more often than not, some of these keystrikes correspond to a "Yes", "No", "Overwrite anyway" or similar option's hotkey. Thus, it happens so that my fingers are typing in a sentence, and my eyes see a flash of some random dialog, but my fingers have already typed in something that closes the dialog. Then I am left baffled, because I absolutely have no idea what I just "clicked" with a hotkey - did I agree to overwrite some important files? Did I perhaps agree to delete some file? Did I abort everything? I cannot know.

To prevent these kinds of horrible accidents, I'd like to disable Windows from "randomly" switching window focus. When I am typing in something, I'd like the focus to stay there and nowhere else. So the idea is that **I** am in control of the focused window, not Windows.

Is there some registry tweak or similar to prevent Windows from changing active window focus automatically?